# Switching between forms in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I’m trying to change forms in Delphi XE7 by hiding the current form and showing the next. I understand similiar questions have been asked on here before but I want my program to work such that if the user closes the current window the entire application will close (currently I have to end the project in task manager if this happens).

Edit: I also have 10 forms in my project and all cannot be auto-created, so how can I use the other available forms?

Comment: This is pretty easy to achieve, so what is your exact problem?

Comment: If the user closes a window, only that window closes and the entire application doesn’t terminate unless you close it from task manager

Comment: Closing an arbitrary form doesn't close the application. Only closing the main form will do so.

Comment: Yes exactly, so how can I make it so that when a form is closed the entire project will close?

Comment: In the Forms OnClose event call `Application.MainForm.Close`.

Comment: When a form is closed, shut down the app. You'll have to write some code.

Comment: @UweRaabe or better, call `Application.Terminate()`, which is what the MainForm calls when it is closed.

Answer (score -4):

In Delphi, app should automatically close itself if user closes a main form.

OnClose event of main form:

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
  frmMain:= nil;
end;
```

Btw you can also terminate your app with **halt** command.